# Trying to change 4 massive subs into 4 threads to save time... threads aren't starting

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, visual-studio-2012

Here's the situation.  Running VS2012, code is in VB.NET, framework is 4.0.  I've got a program that builds a report.  It does various queries to a sql database for about 50,000 different customers, so running the program linearly, it takes about 17 hours on the server, about 36 if I try and do this through debug.  I'm trying to cut this down to something we can run over night, and want to use threading.

There are 4 main subroutines being called in the main_load while produce 4 separate files.  While they do reference the same databases, it's only select statements, and so I should be ok to run them at the same time, right?  So I changed the 4 subroutine calls to this...

```
    Imports System.Data.OleDb
    Imports System.Data.SqlClient
    Imports System.IO
    Imports CDDReports.RiskRatings
    Imports System.Threading

    Public Class Main

    Private Sub Main_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim trd1, trd2, trd3, trd4 As Thread
    trd1 = New Thread(AddressOf RunRiskRatedBusinessReport)
    trd2 = New Thread(AddressOf RunRiskRatedConsumerReport)
    trd3 = New Thread(AddressOf RunRatingVarianceBusinessReport)
    trd4 = New Thread(AddressOf RunRatingVarianceConsumerReport)

    trd1.Start()
    trd2.Start()
    trd3.Start()
    trd4.Start()
    End Sub
    //subroutines defined
    end class
```

But when I run the program, now nothing happens.  Occasionally one or 2 files are created (first few lines of each subroutine create the file) so it looks like it *might* be starting them? but then they exit immediately, and the task scheduler says the process has completed... yet nothing's been run.  What am I doing wrong that these threads either aren't starting, or are ending almost immediately?

Update:  I've added a try catch to the entirety of the subroutines, so if they fail for any reason, it should send out an email... same things happens: process starts and immediately completes, no emails get sent.  I've also added the code below, but nothing changes.  Could threads have permission issues if the main doesn't?

```
    While trd4.ThreadState = ThreadState.Running
        While trd3.ThreadState = ThreadState.Running
            While trd2.ThreadState = ThreadState.Running
                While trd1.ThreadState = ThreadState.Running
                    Thread.Sleep(10000)
                End While
            End While
        End While
    End While
```

Comment: What happens if any of these threads throws an exception?

Comment: technically, nothing.  However, the code is all the same, and this was running fine before I introduced the threading, but it was taking FOREVER.  So I figured I should be able to run them concurrently with the same results...

Comment: Is there code to ensure that you're waiting on the threads to complete?  You're not setting them as background threads, so your main function could complete but leave a thread running in the foreground until it completes or errors out.

Comment: @tencntraze is up to something here. It could very well be that your main process is closing and interrupting all threads in the process. Make sure you are waiting for them to complete.

Comment: that's what I thought, that they should continue, but like I mentioned, the first thing these subroutines do is create a file... and no files are being created.  I'm sure the main thread is completing first, because starting these 4 threads is all the main does... do I need to set it up to wait until they finish?

Comment: I did try 
        While trd4.ThreadState = ThreadState.Running
        While trd3.ThreadState = ThreadState.Running
        While trd2.ThreadState = ThreadState.Running
        While trd1.ThreadState = ThreadState.Running
        Thread.Sleep(10000)
        End While
        End While
        End While
        End While

but no luck... same issue.

Comment: Have you tried using Tasks instead (TPL)? I find TPL has a much more user-friendly programming model.

Comment: @Neolisk I have, same results.  however, I didn't do any changes to the logic... just changed "new thread" to "new tasks.task"

Comment: @Crono I tried the while loop, but no change, except that the program didn't end... still nothing happened though

Comment: I also tried the while loop as just empty... which gave me 99% processor usage, but no new results.

Comment: Ok. Try [Task.WaitAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of your `Thread.Sleep(10000)` loop.